# Doxygen in C preprocessor if

Tags: c, header, documentation, c-preprocessor, doxygen

I document my C-Code with Doxygen and got a problem. Consider following example:

in defines.h:

```
#ifndef DEFINES_H_
#define DEFINES_H_

#define ENABLED 1

#endif
```

in test.c

```
#include <defines.h>

/**
 *  @brief  This is the first testfunction
 *  @return   void
 */
void testFunc1(void)
{
    //...do stuff
}

#if ENABLED
/**
 *  @brief  This is the second testfunction
 *  @return   void
 */
void testFunc2(void)
{
    //...do stuff
}
#endif
```

Doxygen finds testFunc1 and documents it well, but it cannot find testFunc2. To define ENABLED in the .doxyfile wont fix my problem.

Is there a way to get this running? (Note, I need to define ENABLED inside my c-Project!)

Comment: You probably want `#ifdef` instead of `#if`.

Comment: But I define it to 1 (#define ENABLED                                 1)
So #if ENABLED should be true

Comment: @xy36 it was difficult to see it, because the 1 is very far from the rest. I'll edit

Comment: Yes, i saw you already edited it. We work with a space to column 60, so....Thanks

Comment: or rename the `defines.h` file and rebuild. If it still works, means that another file is used with the same name.?

Comment: To clearify, the c-Project works well, it includes the correct header and "knows" testFunc2. The problem is that Doxygen can`t find ENABLED.

Comment: Try `#include "defines.h"` instead of `#include <defines.h>`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Both settings are set to YES

Comment: which explains the 2 upvotes on your question :) check scaiba suggestion. Also, have you tried to include a non-existing file to see if doxygen complains? because it could be an include path issue

Comment: Yes, Doxygen complains when i try to include a non existing file. Doxygen logs "Generating docs for file defines.h", hence it should find the file!

Comment: have you tried to `#define ENABLED 1` directly in the .c file?

Comment: Of course, thats working.

Comment: Do you have trailing newlines on these files? I recall that doxygen preprocessor had some problems if those were missing.

Comment: Could you give me an example for trailings newlines?

Comment: File with trailing newline is just a file that ends in empty line; line break character is the last character in the file.

Comment: Revisiting. I tried the above `defines.h` and `test.c` and I don't see a problem with the current doxygen version (1.8.14). Which version of doxygen are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[misread the source snippet]

<strike>You probably want `#ifdef` instead of `#if`.</strike>

From the docs  for [`#if`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If):

> The `‘#if’` directive allows you to test the value of an arithmetic expression, rather than the mere existence of one macro.
>   Its syntax is
>
> ```
> #if expression
> controlled text
> #endif /* expression */
> ```
>
> *expression* is a C expression of integer type, subject to stringent restrictions.

and for [`#ifdef`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Ifdef.html#Ifdef):

> The simplest sort of conditional is
>
> ```
> #ifdef MACRO
> controlled text
> #endif /* MACRO */
> ```
>
> This block is called a *conditional group*. *controlled text* will be included in the output of the preprocessor if and only if *MACRO* is defined. We say that the conditional *succeeds* if *MACRO* is defined, *fails* if it is not.

Comment: err I just saw: `#define ENABLED                                 1`. The 1 is just ridiculously on the right with a looooot of spaces. So it's not the issue.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Oh well, yes  ... will delete soon.

Comment: my guess is that OP is including the wrong defines.h file.

Comment: It seems that Doxygen can`t include the headerfile and read the #define

Comment: that's possible, yes... can't you add a directive from doxygen command line directly? or in the conf file?

Comment: Yes, i could add "PREDEFINED = ENABLED := 1" in the .doxyfile, but I am looking for another solution where I don`t have to modify the .doxyfile

Comment: @alk wait, changing #if to #ifdef could workaround the issue, if so your answer is somehow valid

Comment: @xy36 try to change #if by #ifdef anyway, maybe doxygen works with #ifdef.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre if I use #ifdef its not working as well